# Calculate entity location (Cartesian coordinate) on a grid (entity & ground tile size different )

Tags: lua, 2d, tile, love2d

**I am trying to write a function that tells on which tiles is stepping my player knowing that [ ground tile size ] is different from [ player tile size ]**

**I want to avoid looping through the whole map at any cost**.

unfortunately, I do not have that level in math which mean I have no clue how to do that.

Im working with a 2D classic cartesian coordinate system like any classic RPG.

I tried to calculate the first tile my player was on and then I was lost. I couldnt do more.

I did something like i = math.floor( entity.x / tile size )
Same for j

then index = ( i + 1 ) + j * nbTilesPerRow

**Actual results :** nothing. Tiles remained undetected, even the [ tile index ] i got from the mentioned formula.

---

```
function Map:ClickedTile( mouseX, mouseY )
    local i = math.floor( mouseX / self.tile.size )
    local j = math.floor( mouseY / self.tile.size )

    local index = i + j * self.tile.width

    return index
end
```

This code works and gives me the tile index I clicked on.

**I want to replicate this to find out all the tiles my player is currently colliding with while avoiding looping through the whole map.**

**Sample data :**

```
tile size = 32 * 32
player tile size = 64 * 64
map size : 25 * 19
```

Thanks for reading me.

Comment: Github link doesn’t work. Also, best if you give a very small example of what you are trying to do: describe, either in code or otherwise, the dimensions of a small map, its tile size, a player tile size, etc. With a small example of typical sizes, the math can probably be figured out easily.

Comment: p.s. make link clickable by using [Markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links).

Comment: @brianolive I added that. Thanks for the comment

Comment: It seems you have all the ingredients that you need: If you are able to click the mouse and determine the tile, then extend that idea to the player tile: Figure out the bottom left corner coordinate of the player tile (probably already have that - its how you placed the tile). With your code above, use that coordinate to determine the map tile it touches. Do the same for the upper right corner. Now you know the tile that  that corner touches. Together you now know the minimum row and column, and maximum row and column. I can work it out in code later, but off to work for now!

Comment: Oh I see. I may got it but if you dont mind I would like to see the code. Im afraid if I do this one on myself it will be veryyy messy ( like the rest of my code anyway.. coding 2D game is so hard, damn..). Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you want the map's tile in the square {x=entity.x, y=entity.y, size=64}

let get all the position:

```lua
function getPosition(map, square)
   local xpos = {}
   for i = square.x, square.x + square.size, map.tile.size do
      table.insert(xpos, math.floor(i / map.tile.size))
   end

   local ypos = {}
   for i = square.y, square.y + square.size, map.tile.size do
      table.insert(ypos, math.floor(i / map.tile.size))
   end
   return xpos, ypos
end
```

with that you have all {x,y} position on your map where the square intersect
(for example for positions square = {x=33,y=33,size=64} you get xpos={1,2,3})

you then have to convert the x,y coordinate into index:

```lua
function positionToIndex(positions, mapWidth)
   local indexes = {}
   for position in ipairs(positions) do
      local index = i + j * mapWidth
      table.insert(indexes, index)
   end
   return indexes
end

local xpos, ypos = getPosition(map, entity)
local position = listOfCoordinate(xpos, ypos)  -- should be straighforward
local intersectionIndexes = positionToIndex(position, map.tile.size)
```

there are some flaw you need to resolve with this:

- what happen when the player is exactly on the tile, the for loop is inclusive boundary ({x=0,y=0,size=64}, does he touch the tile 0,1,2 or 0,1 ?)
- these math are for 0 indexed array
- change the size by width / height to work for rectangle